# How to remove specific empty lines from multi line strings in python?

Tags: python

I am using a template to create multiple .txt files. Some files will have empty values, so I want to remove the resulting empty lines:

```
arg1 = '- this is the third line'
arg2 = '- this is the fourth line'
arg3 = ''
arg4 = '- this is the sixth line'
```

When applied to the template the result is the following content:

(content being a multi line string)

```
This is the first line:

    - this is the third line
    - this is the fourth line

    - this is the sixth line

This is some other content whose possible empty lines need to be left alone.
```

From the template:

```
This is the first line:

    $arg1
    $arg2
    $arg3
    $arg4

This is some other content whose possible empty lines need to be left alone.
```

So before I write this content to a file I want to remove those ugly empty lines, so it looks like this:

```
This is the first line:

        - this is the third line
        - this is the fourth line         
        - this is the sixth line

This is some other content whose possible empty lines need to be left alone.
```

In other words I want to remove all empty lines that fall in the specific range of lines, something like this:

```
for line, index_line in zip(content.splitlines(), range(1, 11)):
    if index_line in range(4, 11) and line == '    ':
        # command that will remove the empty line and save the new content
```

P.S. the ranges are different, since this is my own code snippet, but the ranges for the given example would be:

`range (1, 7)` #stop when we pass the sixth line

`range(3,7)` #check only the lines in the given range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want is `list.pop(index)`.

```
# assuming you have the contents read from the file split into this list:
lines = content.splitlines()

indicestoremove=[]
for index in range (2,6): # or whatever range of lines you want to trim - 
                          # remember indices start from 0 for the first line
    if lines[index] == '':
        indicestoremove.append(index)

# remove in reverse order, as pop() changes the index of items later in the list
for index in sorted(indicestoremove, reverse=True):
    lines.pop(index)

f = open('filename')
for line in lines:
  f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Comment: A previous version of this would not work if there were more than one contiguous lines to remove, as `pop()` changes the structure of the list such that it would skip comparing the next item. Saving the indices and removing in reverse order avoids this.

Answer (score 0):

If the ranges may vary and if we can count on "^-\s" as a flag for when we want to start and stop removing empty lines, then you could use regular expressions.

```
import re

s = '''This is the first line:

    - this is the third line
    - this is the fourth line

    - this is the sixth line


This is some other content whose possible empty lines need to be left alone.

Leave that last line alone.
'''

remove_empty = False
lines = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    l = line.strip()
    if l != '':
        dashed = (re.match('^-\s', l) is not None)
        if dashed and not remove_empty:
            # Now we need to start removing empty strings
            remove_empty = (re.match('^-\s', l) is not None)
        elif not dashed and remove_empty:
            # Now it is time to stop
            remove_empty = False
            lines.append('')

    if l != '' or not remove_empty:
        lines.append(line)

print '\n'.join(lines)
# This is the first line:
#
#     - this is the third line
#     - this is the fourth line
#     - this is the sixth line
#
# This is some other content whose possible empty lines need to be left alone.
#
# Leave that last line alone.
```

If you know the ranges for sure then it looks like Aaron D would have a better solution.